# How can I make a heatmap like the price heatmap of Housing.com

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying for some weeks to come up with a price map. My inspiration is the heatmap found on the website of Housing.com . The link to the map is: 
https://housing.com/dsl/heatmaps/mumbai/buy

I have tried:
Google maps Javascript API 3
heatmap,js library
and many other websites.
The resulting map that I am getting is visually less appealing.
Have they defined boundaries for very small regions and then introduced the gradient(which, again I am unaware how to implement.) 
Any thoughts on how it might have been implemented are welcomed.

Comment: I also want to create heatmap like https://www.zoopla.co.uk/heatmaps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't use Google Maps Heatmaps Layer in the application, or any other library for creating heatmaps. You can see that between the requests the webpage makes are images like [this](https://images-housing.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/heatmaps/price/Mumbai_11_359_228_buy.png), [this](https://images-housing.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/heatmaps/price/Mumbai_11_360_228_buy.png) and also [more](https://images-housing.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/heatmaps/price/Mumbai_13_1438_913_buy.png) for bigger zoom levels. They just render these images over custom styled google maps as tiles.

More on how to render custom tiles over google maps, check [this part of docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes). For more information how to style the map below the heatmap to look like in the example, check [this parts of docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling).

Creating tiles images to render over your google maps can be troublesome, there are some tools, [like this one](https://www.maptiler.com/how-to/overlay-image-over-map/) which should be able to help you, but is paid. I don't know of any free solutions, you can create it manually although it might take some time.

Hope this helps you to better understand the implementation techniques behind the referenced map.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. The google map documentation cleared a lot. So, to change the values of data, they will have to remake the images and re-render them over the google maps? Also, the info box that appears on hovering over a region, can that be achieved without using markers. Or I will have to hard code boundaries and set the text to be displayed. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "to change the values of data, they will have to remake the images and re-render them over the google maps" . You just have create your own images map tiles and then using the api load them over google maps as they do in the docs. About infobox: I think they have just created an invisible `google.maps.Polygon` for the areas and when mouse hovering over them, they would display some popup near mouse cursor. But I would say, since it's complexity, the infobox part is out of scope of this question.

Comment: Clarification: a)The heatmap represent the real-estate prices. b) I assume they would be updating the prices monthly/quarterly. c) If heatmap layer would have been used, the process could be easily automated.They take the prices from their website, feed into csv file and done. d) Since they are creating images, I believe they will have to manually do the process. e) Thanks for the infobox idea. I will try to incorporate that.

Comment: a) yes, b) might be c) yes, but they don't use heatmaps, they use images d) doesn't necessarily have to be manual. They can create a tool which would create images automatically, but that's not trivial, but can be done e) glad I was able to help.

Comment: if the answer helped, please consider up-voting/accepting it.